# Unable to start debugging on the web server. The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

So, I was setting a whole bunch of "unnecessary" windows services to disabled, and then I encountered the:
"Unable to start debugging on the web server. The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly." error.

I think this specific error is a bit different than the typical "Unable to start debugging on the web server", I found very few hits on google.

Anyways, it turns out that debugging relies upon the "COM+ Event System" windows service.

Just FYI.

Comment: @tbone: Where is the question? ;))

Comment: Ya, its not a question, its an answer.  It is a quite rare scenario that I was able to find no other reference to on the internet, so I hope you don't remove it from SO?  I just put it here so this error message is documented on the internet. I'd rather not lose points for this, it is valuable.